# How to render an image when its width is not same with stride?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have 1920x1080 display. BTW it is rotated. So, the display resolution is 1080x1920.

```
DisplayInfo mainDpyInfo;
err = SurfaceComposerClient::getDisplayInfo(mainDpy, &mainDpyInfo);
if (err != NO_ERROR) {
    ALOGE("ERROR: unable to get display characteristics");
    return false;
}

if (mainDpyInfo.orientation != DISPLAY_ORIENTATION_0 &&
    mainDpyInfo.orientation != DISPLAY_ORIENTATION_180) {
    // rotated
    mWidth = mainDpyInfo.h;
    mHeight = mainDpyInfo.w;
} else {
    mWidth = mainDpyInfo.w;
    mHeight = mainDpyInfo.h;
}
ALOGI("[albert] DpyInfo     = %d x %d\n", mainDpyInfo.w, mainDpyInfo.h);
ALOGI("[albert] orientation = %d\n", mainDpyInfo.orientation);
ALOGI("[albert] Actual      = %d x %d\n", mWidth, mHeight);
```

Log says as below

```
01-11 08:29:37.320 I/AlbertApp( 5779): [albertc] DpyInfo     = 1920 x 1080
01-11 08:29:37.320 I/AlbertApp( 5779): [albertc] orientation = 3
01-11 08:29:37.320 I/AlbertApp( 5779): [albertc] Actual      = 1080 x 1920
```

Now I have a render buffer which is allocated by Gralloc.

```
Format    = RGBA
Dimension = 1080*1920
Stride    = 1088
```

I've rendered all textures into this render buffer and will finally render to this buffer to screen.

```
...
pGfxBuffer->lock(GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN, (void**)&tgtPixels);
w = buffer.width;
h = buffer.height;
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureMap);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tgtPixels); 
pGfxBuffer->unlock();
```

After dumping tgtPixels and open it 1088x1920 with raw viewer tool, the image is normal without no corruption.
But the image presented on the screen is corrupted.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: FYI. In 1088x1920 buffer, 8 lines at the right side are not effective image so they are all black. Only 1080x1920 pixels contains what I want to render to the screen.

Comment: Adjust the UV coordinates to match the difference. I'm guessing this is video?

Comment: You mean I should adjust texture coordinate? IFor example, (1.0f, 1080.0f/1088.0f) for right top coordinate??

Comment: You can do that but other video files/streams might have more padding pixels, ie 16 or none even, so you'll have to account for that. You might also find ffmpeg will spit out frames with random padding. I got around this by sws_scale'ing copying the buffer without convert the size or or pixel format into my own buffer of the videos actual width and height.